# How to center toolbar back button?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

I'm having a problem trying to center the back button on the support toolbar.
I'm using it inside an ActionBarActivity.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:toolbar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    toolbar:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    toolbar:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

And set the up navigation inside the Activity's `onCreate()` like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_scanner);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

However, what I'm getting is this:

[image]

As you can see the back button is misplaced

Edit:
The problem seems to lie in a custom value for `?attr/actionBarSize` set to 40dp, however, it turns out now, that it's the title that is misplaced instead.

Comment: One of the action I think disable that back button and put a button widget inside and align it as you want. Hope it helps!!!

Comment: can you remove minHeight tag and add height as "?attr/actionBarSize" instead of "wrap_content"

Comment: @Viren I would like to avoid rediscovering the wheel if possible

Comment: @RiyazAhamed please check updated question, it's actually the title that make the toolbar grow, but the back button should adapt as well

Answer (score 102, accepted):

From the [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) :

> Toolbar supports a more focused feature set than ActionBar. From start
>   to end, a toolbar may contain a combination of the following optional
>   elements:
>
> A navigation button. This may be an Up arrow, navigation menu toggle,
>   close, collapse, done or another glyph of the app's choosing. This
>   button should always be used to access other navigational destinations
>   within the container of the Toolbar and its signified content or
>   otherwise leave the current context signified by the Toolbar. **The
>   navigation button is vertically aligned within the Toolbar's minimum
>   height, if set.**

So if you set *minHeight* attribute the same as your toolbar height (*layout_height* ), the back arrow will be centered vertically.

Comment: I was using a custom `toolbar:theme` so my problem was solved  by removing `<item name="android:actionBarSize">@android:/abc_action_bar_stacked_max_height</item>`  from my `toolbar's theme`

Comment: If use support v7 before 24,we can set `maxButtonHeight` equal `android:minHeight ` make a vertical center effect. After v7 version >=24+,we can set attr `buttonGravity` .

Comment: Had to add `android:minHeight="@null"` to cancel out the `minHeight` coming from the toolbar style `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar"`

Answer (score 15):

**(2020)**

In case you have a non-standard toolbar height, to center the back button nowadays (2k20) with `androidx` `Toolbar` you can just use the `buttonGravity` property.

This allows you to use `wrap_content` instead of a specific height (`minHeight` doesn't allow you to do so):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
   app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ... />
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!
 I wonder if there's a minimum API version for this?

Comment: @LuckMan I haven't seen any specific requirements for the Toolbar itself, I think it's safe to assume that `androidx.widget.*` work on API 14+ (Android 4.0) -- AFAIK, that was the requirement of the pre-androix support lib.

Answer (score 2):

Inside ActionBarActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  getSupportActionBat().setTitle("Hello World"); 
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Layout code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
```

And style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
```

Remember that toolbar is just viewgroup, so u can style it in any way u like.
Here is image link : [Toolbar sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUNkd.png)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve this is remove regular Back button from the toolbar and add a custom ImageButton in your XML layout and set image to it. You can place this ImageButtton wherever you want on the toolbar.

Your activity layout code should be something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:src="@drawable/attach_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of [@Rick Sanchez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964331/3801327) - if you know the size of the Toolbar's `minHeight` attribute you can then use:

```
android:gravity="top"
app:titleMarginTop="@dimen/margin_to_center"
```

in the Toolbar to center the text. If you are using `android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"` then this would be about 13p

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the solutions worked. In my case the problem was the margin I applied:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ... >

     <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

After applying it to the toolbar directly, the button was centered vertically:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     ... >

     <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rick Sanchez answer is work,setup Toolbar's layout_height the same as minHeight

I found in Toolbar constructor have a field can setup button gravity,
`mButtonGravity = a.getInteger(R.styleable.Toolbar_buttonGravity, Gravity.TOP);`

,but v7 support Toolbar can not setup,
`mButtonGravity = Gravity.TOP;`

Answer (score 0):

make your button size `56dp` and set `scaleType` to `center` with no margins on `Appbar`
Make sure your icon is `24x24` dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I was using

```
  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

when I should've been using

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
```