# How to vertically center menu item on toolbar less than 48dp?

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I'm trying to vertical center a simple menu item on my 30dp height toolbar.  I realize that Material Guidelines suggests a toolbar of 48dp, but I have too many items in my screen to give up any real estate.  There must be a way of vertically centering the menu item in my toolbar??

Menu Inflation:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Function"
        android:id="@+id/menu_func_keys"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image: un-centered menu item]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know it is a bit late, but if it helps...

The answer was found in this other thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964331/8050896

Basically Android centers the menu items according to the *minHeight* parameter in your Toolbar. So set as so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:minHeight="Whatever your toolbar height is">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Menu items should be centered now!

Comment: Thanks. Now it's moved to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.